# Using angular2 and about some questions in IIS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, iis-7

I am a new learner in angular 2.
In the past, I was include the js(ex jquery.js...) in my html and put the finished html into the IIS website

When I start to learn angular 2, install the node js , npm , typescript...etc.
It seems that node js like a server ?

My target is that using the angular 2 framework,
But my server is using IIS.

How can I combine the node js/npm/typescript with IIS ?

Maybe it's a stupid question but it really confuses me

Answer (score 0):

You may easily use Angular 2 with IIS.
IIS is Web server which hosts your web application and you may host any HTML\JS(not limited to) based application easily.

The only thing you need to take care is compiling of Typescript\Style file, there are multiple ways of doing that,

you may write your own Gulp\Webpack tasks to do that, or you may use Angular-CLI. Once that is done it is a simple website which IIS can easily serve.

Hope this helps!!